# Creating initial CouchDB database with millions of documents

Tags: database, couchdb, migrating

I have a Postgres database with many millions of records that I want to migrate to CouchDB. I know how I want to represent the records as documents, each document will have 9 items (4 integers, 4 text strings, and a date string).

My question is: Do I really need to write something that's going to have to do millions and millions of POST requests to create my initial database from the existing data? I understand that CouchDB is generally fast but doing this over HTTP strikes me as extremely inefficient and time consuming to do over even localhost HTTP.

HTTP is the only API that I see, so is this normally what is done when someone has to create a database with a huge number of initial documents?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is done via http. It is not inefficient though, since you can create multiple documents in one request by using the [_bulk_docs API](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.x/api/database.html#post-db-bulk-docs).

Comment: thanks, this worked for the most part though we had to break the data into smaller bits